# How to deploy war file in tomcat7 ubuntu 12.0.4 server

Tags: tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04, java-ee-6, war, web-deployment

I need to deploy war file in tomcat7..
What I have done so far is
1. Installed Tomcat7 - up and running. Able to see index page 
2. Installed apache2 - up and running. successfully redirects 80 to 8080 port of tomcat. 'All' requests are redirected to tomcat. 
3. Now I need to deploy war file.

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/
├── common
│   └── classes
├── conf -> /etc/tomcat7
├── logs -> ../../log/tomcat7
├── server
│   └── classes
├── shared
│   └── classes
├── webapps
│   ├── mycompany.war
│   └── ROOT
│       ├── index.html
│       └── META-INF
│           └── context.xml
└── work -> ../../cache/tomcat7

/etc/tomcat7/
├── Catalina
│   └── localhost
├── catalina.properties
├── context.xml
├── logging.properties
├── policy.d
│   ├── 01system.policy
│   ├── 02debian.policy
│   ├── 03catalina.policy
│   ├── 04webapps.policy
│   └── 50local.policy
├── server.xml
├── tomcat-users.xml
└── web.xml

/usr/share/tomcat7/
├── bin
│   ├── bootstrap.jar
│   ├── catalina.sh
│   ├── catalina-tasks.xml
│   ├── configtest.sh
│   ├── daemon.sh
│   ├── digest.sh
│   ├── setclasspath.sh
│   ├── shutdown.sh
│   ├── startup.sh
│   ├── tomcat-juli.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-juli.jar
│   ├── tool-wrapper.sh
│   └── version.sh
├── conf -> /var/lib/tomcat7/conf
├── defaults.md5sum
├── defaults.template
├── lib
│   ├── annotations-api.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-annotations-api-7.0.26.jar
│   ├── catalina-ant.jar -> ../../java/catalina-ant-7.0.26.jar
│   ├── catalina-ha.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-catalina-ha-7.0.26.jar
│   ├── catalina.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-catalina-7.0.26.jar
│   ├── catalina-tribes.jar -> ../../java/catalina-tribes-7.0.26.jar
│   ├── commons-dbcp.jar -> ../../java/commons-dbcp.jar
│   ├── commons-pool.jar -> ../../java/commons-pool.jar
│   ├── el-api.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-el-api-2.2.jar
│   ├── jasper-el.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-jasper-el-7.0.26.jar
│   ├── jasper.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-jasper-7.0.26.jar
│   ├── jsp-api.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-jsp-api-2.2.jar
│   ├── servlet-api.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-servlet-api-3.0.jar
│   ├── tomcat-api.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-api-7.0.26.jar
│   ├── tomcat-coyote.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-coyote-7.0.26.jar
│   ├── tomcat-i18n-es.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-i18n-es-7.0.26.jar
│   ├── tomcat-i18n-fr.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-i18n-fr-7.0.26.jar
│   ├── tomcat-i18n-ja.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-i18n-ja-7.0.26.jar
│   └── tomcat-util.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-util-7.0.26.jar
└── webapps -> /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps
```

my war is not detected nor expanded. No logs.. No 'mycompany' directory created.

I checked my server.xml below is the code

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Do I miss something... Why tomcat is not taking the deployed war file ????

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out?

Comment: Please do restart tomcat

Comment: Did you find the solution to this as I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, what I did was:

- Add permissions on my .war file
- Add permissions on the /webapps directory
- Restart tomcat

After this it began to work, so hopefully doing one of those helps anyone having the same issue.

Comment: please describe the permissions you added